# How to disable auto "go to location" on paste in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

In Firefox pasting through middle click somewhere in the web page lets Firefox go there. I do not know, if this behaviour is really new, but in the course of the last few weeks it has become annoying, since I cannot stop my fingers from doing accidental middle clicks on track pads. I would not expect this behaviour anyway and it actually took me some time to figure out what was happening.

Can I disable the go to "feature" after pastes in the content window of firefox somehow? I know how to disable middle click paste altogether, but I need that feature in actual form input elements and even more so in the location and search bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not new; it existed in Mozilla even before Firefox, and has been the default on Unix/Linux systems forever. You can toggle it using `middlemouse.contentLoadURL` in *about:config*.